# monitor httpwebrequest traffic when using proxies?

Tags: c#, proxy, httpwebrequest, fiddler

I have a program which uses httpwebrequest to automate a few things on my company's web site. The program works perfectly when not using proxies at home, but at work I need to use proxies but the problem is when I use a proxy I get unexpected results. Is there anyway to monitor httpwebrequest's traffic with Fiddler when using a proxy so I can find what is the reason for getting unexpected results?

Regards!

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. Fiddler works just fine with upstream proxies, as clearly explained on the Fiddler website.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend http://www.charlesproxy.com/ for HTTP(S) debugging.

Comment: Charles has no advantage over Fiddler for this task.